# Highlight variable under cursor in Vim like in NetBeans

Tags: vim, netbeans, highlight

I worked in NetBeans and liked this feature: when you place cursor in a variable name all occurences of the variable are highlighted. This is very useful for quick searching all occurences of the variable. Is it possible to add this behavior to Vim?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This autocommand will do what you want:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * exe printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
```

[image: vi highlight current word]

**Edit:** I have used the `IncSearch` highlight group in my example, but you can find other colours to use by running this command:

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim
```

Comment: if I move the cursor on the end of a C-style comment (star followed by slash), I get `E488: Trailing characters: match IncSearch /\<*/\>`, and I even have to press Enter before continuing, pretty annoying! I guess it should be escaped somehow and/or at least it would be ok to find a way to silence the warning. Great tip anyway.

Comment: ok, easy enough, I just had to change it to `:autocmd CursorMoved * silent! exe printf('match IncSearch /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))`

Comment: @UncleZeiv: I have fixed the answer to escape the pattern. The "silent!" only suppresses errors - it is better to fix the cause of them.. ;)

Comment: Could any charitable soul explain how does this command work?

Comment: Netbeans would highlight the variables that accessible with the context of currently chosen variable. It knows the difference between the same variable declared within lamda function and a normal function that contained it and will highlight accordingly. Is it possible to introduce that kind of language specific intelligence in highlighting?

Comment: @SenG Well one could always rely on the brain to that or simply don't use the same variable in nested sematic scopes which is confusing anyway and should be avoided. That being said, take a look at "Eclim" if it has the ability to enumerate all occurences of a semantic entity, then you could use that command instead of "match" for highlighting. But I guess this will be terribly inefficient and only for Java. On second thought I take that back. Use "match" and just be happy that you found smelly code thanks to vim ;).

Comment: Is it possible to not have the word at the cursor highlighted? This works a treat but can be a little easy to loose your place on the screen.

Comment: This works great! I'm wondering if anyone can point me to making this work across all open files. Situation: function definition in file A, usage in file B. Screen split as A and B. When cursor over function name in either file, would like to see occurrences across both files be highlighted.

Comment: @SenG - at this point I'd look to use a language-aware IDE, and perhaps one with a VIM emulation (e.g. Intellij + IdeaVIM plugin - not ideal, but bridges the IDE and Vim world quite well)

Answer (score 24):

If you set

```
:set hlsearch
```

to highlight all occurrences of a search pattern, and then use `*` or `#` to find occurrences of the word under your cursor, that will get you some way to what you want. However I think a syntax-aware variable highlighting is beyond the scope of VIM.

Comment: your solution is great! the only problem is when I use * the cursor jumps over to the next search result. Isn't it possible to keep cursor on the current word?

Comment: @Meysam - you can create a simple mapping which does just that (untested): nmap <leader>* *N

Comment: As an addition to lukaszkorecki's comment: If you want the cursor to stay at same position you could use ```nmap <leader>* `` ``` (doubled backtick)

Answer (score 9):

This statement will allow a variable to enable/disable highlighting all occurences of the word under the cursor:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * exe exists("HlUnderCursor")?HlUnderCursor?printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\')):'match none':""
```

One would activate highlighting with:

```
:let HlUnderCursor=1
```

And disable it with:

```
:let HlUnderCursor=0
```

One could easily define a shortcut key for enabling/disabling highlighting:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F3> :exe "let HlUnderCursor=exists(\"HlUnderCursor\")?HlUnderCursor*-1+1:1"<CR>
```

Deleting the variable would prevent the match statement from executing, and not clear the current highlight:

```
:unlet HlUnderCursor
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to highlight language words (statements / preprocs such as `if`, `#define`) when your cursor is on these words, you can put this function in your `.vimrc` based on the @too_much_php answer :

```
let g:no_highlight_group_for_current_word=["Statement", "Comment", "Type", "PreProc"]
function s:HighlightWordUnderCursor()
    let l:syntaxgroup = synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), stridx(getline("."), expand('<cword>')) + 1, 1)), "name")

    if (index(g:no_highlight_group_for_current_word, l:syntaxgroup) == -1)
        exe printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
    else
        exe 'match IncSearch /\V\<\>/'
    endif
endfunction

autocmd CursorMoved * call s:HighlightWordUnderCursor()
```

Answer (score 5):

i think that what you really want is the following plugin by Shuhei Kubota:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4306

According to the description: 'This script highlights words under the cursor like many IDEs.'

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[`vim_current_word`](https://github.com/dominikduda/vim_current_word) works out of the box, is syntax aware, and allows customisable colours.

Answer (score 1):

To map F2 to toggle highlighting:

```
map <F2> :set hlsearch!<CR> * #
```

It is certainly not perfect. '* #' jumps around a bit much...

Answer (score 0):

This variant is optimized for speed (uses CursorHold instead of CursorMoved) and compatibility with `hlsearch`. The current search word highlighting will not be disrupted.

```
" autosave delay, cursorhold trigger, default: 4000ms
setl updatetime=300

" highlight the word under cursor (CursorMoved is inperformant)
highlight WordUnderCursor cterm=underline gui=underline
autocmd CursorHold * call HighlightCursorWord()
function! HighlightCursorWord()
    " if hlsearch is active, don't overwrite it!
    let search = getreg('/')
    let cword = expand('<cword>')
    if match(cword, search) == -1
        exe printf('match WordUnderCursor /\V\<%s\>/', escape(cword, '/\'))
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, but this way allows you to set a delay time after holding the cursor over a word before the highlighting will appear. The `1000` is in milliseconds and means that it will highlight after 1 second.

```
set updatetime=1000

autocmd CursorHold * exe 
    \ printf('match IncSearch /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
```

See `:h CursorHold` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[vim-illuminate](https://github.com/RRethy/vim-illuminate) does the trick for me.

<del>[match-up](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup#c2-highlight-all-matches) does the trick for me.</del>

> vim match-up: even better % navigate and highlight matching words modern matchit and matchparen
>
> ### Features
>
> - jump between matching words
> - jump to open & close words
> - jump inside (z%)
> - full set of text objects
> - highlight (), [], & {}
> - **highlight all matching words**
> - display matches off-screen
> - show where you are (breadcrumbs)
> - (neovim) tree-sitter integration