# eclipse evidence of variable

Tags: eclipse, vim, selection

one of the best feature i have in eclipse is this one:

if i select (with double click) a word that is a variable name all occurences in the scope are evidenced. and, also, in they are evidenced with a little white rectangle in the scrollbar.

for example with this code:

```
static void foo() {
    int a=0;
    cout << a << endl;
}

static void foo1() {
    int a=1;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

and i select the a in foo(), a in foo1 is not evidenced.

what is the name of this feature? there is something similar in vim?

thanks.

Comment: Here is a recent question which is somewhat related, especially regarding scoping: [Highlight arguments in function body in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9348687/575497). (But there isn't an answer yet!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is called "Highlight occurrences".

In VIM, you can have something similar by activating `hlsearch`.

```
:set hlsearch
```

Then just perform a search using `/`. If you want this to permanent, add it to your .vimrc file.

In normal mode, if you press `*` it will search for the next occurrence of the current word and will highlight the matches if `hlsearch` is set.

Comment: sorry, in the example i've written, if i set hlsearch and then search with /a, it highlight all letter 'a', even in word static

Comment: the nerverending power of vim

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have multiple choices.

Here are two good links:

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags

In vim, you can enter this command:

```
:help tags
```

From the command line, use these commands (assuming Linux or similar):

```
info ctags
```

or

```
ctags --help
```